# SQL: Getting Sum of Row Column Values

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

I have a recipes table with the following info (There are 3 different dishType breakfast, lunch and main course but couldn't fit them and there are 100 rows of each:

[image]

I'm making a recipe web app where the user can enter how many calories they want in a day divided into 3 meals.

I'm trying to query in sql to retrieve 3 rows where each row has each dishtype and have the sum of each calories column less than or equal to a certain value and have each row distinct from each other so that no row has the same title

So far I have a query that returns 3 rows, one of each dish, but with max calories for each dish rather than the total of all the 3 rows (here I set it to >= 500).

```
SELECT title, id, calories, dishType  
FROM livewell.recipes
where calories >=500
group by dishType
LIMIT 3
```

You can also see the lunch and main course have the same title but different ids so they are both in the lunch and dinner category but as mentioned above I'm looking to have no row with the same title

[image]

I'm definitely not an expert in SQL but I've been trying to find out the best way to do this, so I've tried looking for ways to make multiple select queries in one query (so that each query will be for each dishType and then join them all together in one select query):

```
SELECT (
    SELECT * 
    FROM livewell.recipes
    where dishType = 'breakfast'
    order by rand()
    limit 1
), (
SELECT * 
    FROM livewell.recipes
    where dishType = 'lunch'
    order by rand()
    limit 1
), (
SELECT * 
    FROM livewell.recipes
    where dishType = 'main course'
    order by rand()
    limit 1
)
```

Which gives me this error:

`Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same table to do this **UNION** and for this case its more simple using more than 1 where in the same QUERY:

```
Select *
from livewell.recipes
where dishType IN ('lunch', 'main course', 'breakfast')
```

To create a If you can use this function, but o dont understand exactly what you want and i will just show an exemple:

```
   Select *,
    (Case when calories > 500 then calories else 0 end) as IF_EXEMPLE
    from livewell.recipes
    where dishType IN ('lunch', 'main course', 'breakfast')
```

Comment: I've updated the post and code to and make it a bit clearer to understand.

I'm essentially trying to make a query that will return 3 rows, with each row being a different dish type, no rows having the same title and the sum of each rows calories totalling a given value (e.g 1500).